# Using Codeigniter, how do I hide Paypal credentials from other developers?

Tags: php, mysql, git, codeigniter, paypal

Couldn't find a good answer to this on here.

So basically I am using bitbucket.org as my git system. My application uses paypal credentials such as api username, password, signature. What would be the best and most secure way to hide these credentials from other developers who will check out and work on my code?

I use LAMP stack. CodeIgniter framework.

I was thinking of having a serialized file that I don't add to git, put it also on live server, then unserialize it and pull the credentials from it.

Comment: This is highly dependent on your platform, deployment, and configuration. You should probably include that information. As a side note... if you can't trust your developers... I would be far more concerned with that.

Comment: @AdamGent Added!. The other programmers are outsourced so I rather be safe than sorry.

Comment: Well I hope you handle the deployment and production severs otherwise they will be able to see your credentials :)

Comment: Yes I am handling everything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to handle this any differently than you do your database configuration files.

First, create `application/config/paypal.php`:

```
// Change this information to match your settings
//$config['paypal_seekrit'] = '';
// whatever else
```

Note, create it *just* like that, as you're going to track it initially as a stub. Add it and commit it:

```
git add application/config/paypal.php
git commit
```

Now, add it to `.gitignore` so it's no longer tracked locally. Add and commit `.gitignore`. Then, in your code, you need to then do something like this to make sure people remember to set things appropriately:

```
$this->load->config('paypal');
$seekrit = $this->config->item('paypal_seekrit');
if ($seekrit === FALSE) {
    // config->item returns FALSE by default if item doesn't exist
    log_message('error', 'You need to configure config/paypal.php!');
    // bail out, if appropriate
    show_error('Paypal keys have not been configured');
}
```

At this point you can push. Everyone now has a stub of the file, and nothing anyone does on their end will be in danger of being pushed back. The drawback is, if you need to change the default stub to add or remove an option, you (and everyone else) will need to merge. But, it's such a trivial file, I don't consider that an issue.

Then, add your secret keys to the file without worrying about accidentally committing and pushing them. Note, if using it in a library you first have to call `get_instance()` to get at the framework super object (singleton), e.g:

```
$CI = get_instance();
$CI->load->config('paypal');
$seekrit = $CI->config->item('paypal_seekrit');
...
```

One of the first things I do on a new CI project is commit `application/` and then stop tracking certain files in `application/config`.

You can also just make a catch all config file for site specific settings that overrides all previously loaded configurations and stick it in there (something like `config/appname.php`). Just be sure to do it in a way where the config / loader class work as someone would expect them to work.

Answer (score 1):

You could:

1) Use environment variables that you set locally and only reference them by environment variable name in the code.

Elaborating as per request: You could set environment variables locally through .bashrc or the like using:
         `EXPORT PAYPALUSERNAME=mypaypalusername`

```
     `EXPORT PAYPALPASSWORD=mypaypalpassword`


     `EXPORT PAYPALSIGNATURE=mypaypalsignature`
```

And then in your code:

```
     $paypalusername = getenv(PAYPALUSERNAME);
```

Finally in your README you would say something like:

```
     This code sets the username based on your PAYPALUSERNAME environment variable, please make sure to set it in your code
```

2) Use a configuration language of some sort (yml comes to mind), to set up you api credentials, set up your code to read/parse the config file, and not check in the yml file.

In either case a README and/or comments will be necessary so that other developers know how to work with your app.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the first part?

Answer (score 1):

Store your credentials in a config file. Take a look at PHP's `parse_ini_file` function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php

Since you're using codeigntor, you can also use: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/config.html

You could then have a build script of sorts that generates a config file, or use PayPal sandbox credentials (if you want to check-in a config file).

Answer (score 1):

I usualy create some `config.example.ini.php` which is committed into Git repository. When installing application, I copy this file to `config.ini.php` and fill all sensitive data. Also, `.gitignore` contains `config.ini.php`, so this file will not be committed accidentaly.

The extension `.ini.php` only means, that it is INI file that contains `__halt_compiler();` in comment at the first line, so direct requests to this file will show nothing. To load this file I use `parse_ini_file()` function.

Answer (score 0):

look at CodeIgniter environments. you can set any of the config/ files in a localhost, development, etc directory, git ignore those, and then just put sandbox creds into the folder that's visible

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/environments.html